# Strange characters in logcat

Tags: logging

I'm by no means an android developer, so excuse me if that's a stupid question.

I'm trying to debug an app from my (Austrian) bank, which doesn't let me access my NFC-SIM - some problems with the OpenMobile API.

While viewing a logcat of the app, I discovered some strange characters (one Arabic `ٻ` and one supposedly Canadian `ᒲ`) and wondered if this is just some mistakes of the app/log or if this universally stands for something in android logs. I didn't find **anything** regarding these characters, so I thought I'm just gonna ask here. What are these strange characters in the logcat?

Here are two lines:

```
02-19 16:29:30.597 14595 14595 E ٻ      :       at o.ﺕ$ˊ.onSecureElementNotAvailable(SourceFile:123)

02-19 16:29:30.597 14595 14595 W ᒲ     :      at o.ت$ˊ.onSecureElementNotAvailable(SourceFile:123)
```

If this does matter somehow, I have a OnePlus 6T.

Comment: Certainly not universal. Based on [Android Developers Official Site](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat), the format should be `date time PID-TID/package priority/tag: message`. The one with the strange characters are after the priority (E: Error, W: Warning) and should be followed by a forward slash character ("/"). Might be a Unicode jumbled-up, though I don't know why...

Comment: They can be ignored imo